# Revoke client certificate and update the CRL

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, pki

I have a script which creates a CA with a CRL, a client certificate and signs it, and finally revokes it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xeuo pipefail

SERVICE=svc
CA_DIR=client/$SERVICE/ca

# Create CA
mkdir -p "$CA_DIR"
touch "$CA_DIR/ca.index"
openssl rand -hex 16 > "$CA_DIR/ca.serial"



openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -aes-256-cbc -out "$CA_DIR/ca.key" -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
chmod 400 "$CA_DIR/ca.key"

openssl req -new -out "$CA_DIR/ca.crt" -config "$CA_DIR/ca.conf" -x509 -days 365 -key "$CA_DIR/ca.key"

openssl x509 -in "$CA_DIR/ca.crt" -out "$CA_DIR/ca.pem" -outform PEM

CRL_DIR="$CA_DIR/crl"
mkdir -p "$CRL_DIR"
touch "$CRL_DIR/index.txt"
echo 00 > "$CRL_DIR/number"

openssl ca -gencrl -keyfile "$CA_DIR/ca.key" -cert "$CA_DIR/ca.crt" -out $CRL_DIR/crl.pem -config "$CRL_DIR/crl.conf"

# Create user certificate
USER=alice
CRT_DIR=client/$SERVICE/$USER

mkdir -p "$CRT_DIR"



## Create a new certificate
openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout "$CRT_DIR/client.key" -out "$CRT_DIR/client.csr" -config "$CRT_DIR/client.conf"

## Sign it with our CA
openssl ca -config "$CA_DIR/ca.conf" -cert "$CA_DIR/ca.crt" -keyfile "$CA_DIR/ca.key" -out "$CRT_DIR/client.crt" -infiles "$CRT_DIR/client.csr"

## Export client key
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in "$CRT_DIR/client.crt" -inkey "$CRT_DIR/client.key" -out "$CRT_DIR/client.p12"
openssl pkcs12 -in "$CRT_DIR/client.p12" -out "$CRT_DIR/client.pem" -clcerts

echo "Browser key: $PWD/$CRT_DIR/client.p12"
echo "PEM key: $PWD/$CRT_DIR/client.pem"

# revoke
CRT_FILE=$CRT_DIR/client.pem
openssl ca -config "$CA_DIR/ca.conf" -cert "$CA_DIR/ca.crt" -keyfile "$CA_DIR/ca.key" -revoke "$CRT_FILE"
openssl ca -config "$CA_DIR/ca.conf" -cert "$CA_DIR/ca.crt" -keyfile "$CA_DIR/ca.key" -gencrl -out "$CA_DIR/crl/revoked.crl"
```

I also have these files:

- `client/svc/alice/client.conf`

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
encrypt_key = no
default_md = sha256
string_mask = utf8only
utf8 = yes
prompt = no
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = distinguished_name

[ req_ext ]
basicConstraints = CA:false


keyUsage = keyEncipherment, digitalSignature

[ distinguished_name ]
commonName = alice client certificate for my.svc

[ alt_names ]
```

- `client/svc/ca/ca.conf`

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
encrypt_key = yes
default_md = sha256
string_mask = utf8only
utf8 = yes
prompt = no
x509_extensions = x509_ext
distinguished_name = distinguished_name

[ x509_ext ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
nameConstraints = critical, @name_constraints
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
issuerAltName = issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer:always

keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign

[ distinguished_name ]
commonName = svc client Root Certificate Authority

[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
base_dir = client/svc/ca
database = $base_dir/ca.index
serial = $base_dir/ca.serial
new_certs_dir = client/svc/ca
crl = crl.pem
crl_dir = crl
default_md = sha256
default_days = 365
email_in_dn = no
policy = server_policy
copy_extensions = copy
uniqueSubject = no

[ server_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional

[ ca_policy ]
countryName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = supplied
localityName = supplied
organizationName = supplied
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = supplied


[ name_constraints ]
permitted;DNS.0 = my.local
```

- `client/svc/ca/crl/crl.conf`

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default

[ crl_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer:always

[ distinguished_name ]
commonName = svc client Root Certificate Authority CRL

[ CA_default ]
base_dir = client/svc/ca/crl
crl = $base_dir/crl.pem
crlnumber = $base_dir/number
database = $base_dir/index.txt
default_crl_days = 30
default_md = default
default_days = 365
```

Sadly, the whole process ends with:

```
cannot lookup how long until the next CRL is issued
```

`client/svc/ca/crl/revoked.crl` is empty

and the CRL didn't change:

```
openssl crl -in client/svc/ca/crl/crl.pem -text -noout
Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: /CN=svc client Root Certificate Authority
        Last Update: Aug 17 14:18:13 2023 GMT
        Next Update: Sep 16 14:18:13 2023 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 CRL Number: 
                0
No Revoked Certificates.
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: Not a programming or development issue, but `crl.pem` didn't change because you didn't write to it, and `revoked.crl` is empty _because_ the second `-gencrl` gave an error because you used `ca.conf` which doesn't have the required setting(s) not `crl.conf` which does. But `crl.conf` wouldn't work either because it uses a different `database`; you MUST use the SAME `database` to issue the cert AND revoke the cert AND generate the CRL -- so it's counterproductive to have a separate config OR a separate directory; the CRL operations should be part of the CA function.